# how to evaluate definite integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $\lambda_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , then

1.$\lambda_n $ does not exist for some n

2.$\lambda_n $ exists for every n and the sequence is unbounded

3.$\lambda_n $ exists for every n and the sequence is bounded.

4.$\lim_{x \to 0} (\lambda_n)^{1/n}=1$

Put $t=\tan^2\theta$, therefore$\lambda_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}= 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin\theta  \cos^{2n-3}\theta  d\theta$

How to integrate further?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (for $n\neq 0, 1$):
$$\lambda_n = \frac{(1+t)^{1-n}}{1-n}\big|_{t= 0}^{t = 1} = \frac{2^{1-n} - 1}{1-n} $$

And for $n=0, 1$:

$$\lambda_1 = \ln(1+t)\big|_{t= 0}^{t = 1} = \ln(2), \lambda_0 = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

You can decide the first three items without any computation. Indeed, the integrand is bounded (in $[0,\frac12]$) for all $n$ and the integral is over a finite interval, hence the $\lambda_n$ are bounded (certainly by $\frac12$). In addition, they form a decreasing sequence.

Item $4$ makes no sense as there is no $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda_n=\dfrac{1-2^{1-n}}{n-1}$

Does not exist for $n=1$ because $\lambda_1=\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\dfrac{dt}{1+t}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\log 2-\log\epsilon\right)=+\infty$

you have $\lambda_n\leq \dfrac{1}{2};\;\forall n\geq 2$ furthermore $\lambda_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \lambda_n^{1/n}=1$

Indeed if you take the log of the limit you get

$\log\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \lambda_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\log\lambda_n=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\log\lambda_n=0$

so the limit is $e^0=1$

hope this helps

Comment: $logL=lim_{n\to{0}}{\frac{log\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n-1}\right)}{n}}-{\frac{log(n-1)}{n}}$=$0-lim_{n\to{\infty}}\frac{log(n-1)}{n}$=$0-lim_{n\to\infty\frac{1}{n-1}}$=0 , using L'Hospitals Rule , so the limit is $e^0=1$. correct?